# Stop on mouse over on a simple jquery slider

Tags: jquery, slider, slideshow, slide

I have a real simple jquery slider, it fits well for my use.
Just linked images, no controls, thumbs, nothing, really simple!

I'm trying to make it stoo while the mouse cursor is over it, but i wasn't able to.
Can anyone help me here?

slider.js

```
function slideSwitch()
    {
        var $active = $('#slideshow a.active');
        if ( $active.length == 0 ) $active = $('#slideshow a:last');
        var $next =  $active.next().length ? $active.next()
        : $('#slideshow a:first');

        $active.addClass('last-active');

        $next.css({opacity: 0.0})
        .addClass('active')
        .animate({opacity: 1.0}, 1000, function()
        {
            $active.removeClass('active last-active');
        });
}
$(function()
{
    setInterval( "slideSwitch()", 10000 );
});
```

slider.css

```
#slideshow { height: 300px; position: relative; width: 960px; }
#slideshow a { left: 0; opacity: 0.0; position: absolute; top: 0; z-index: 8; }
#slideshow a.active { opacity: 1.0; z-index:10; }
#slideshow a.last-active { z-index: 9; }
```

HTML

```
    <div id="slideshow">
        <a href="#" class="active"><img src="img/slideshow/slide1.png" alt="Engine - Development Solutions" /></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="img/slideshow/slide2.png" alt="Engine - Development Solutions" /></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="img/slideshow/slide3.png" alt="Engine - Development Solutions" /></a>
    </div>
```

THANKS!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Could you describe what happened when you weren't able to?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll want to clear the interval on mouseenter, then start the slider again on mouseleave. You can use jQuery's [hover()](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) function as a shortcut:

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/7yCyR/)

```
$(function() {
    var interval = setInterval( slideSwitch, 10000 );

    $('#slideshow').hover(function() {
        clearInterval(interval);
    }, function() {
        interval = setInterval( slideSwitch, 10000 );
    });
});
```

Comment: @KauêPorte Great! Glad to help! Since this answered your question, would you mark it as accepted? That will help people who have a similar question find the right answer. Thanks and good luck!

Answer (score 1):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/89gm6/1/)**

TRY this, on hover it will pause and ,on mouse leave it will begin from the time paused, not from the begining

```
function slideSwitch()
    {
        var $active = $('#slideshow a.active');
        if ( $active.length == 0 ) $active = $('#slideshow a:last');
        var $next =  $active.next().length ? $active.next()
        : $('#slideshow a:first');

        $active.addClass('last-active');

        $next.css({opacity: 0.0})
        .addClass('active')
        .animate({opacity: 1.0}, 1000, function()
        {
            $active.removeClass('active last-active');
        });
}


$(function()
{  var a;
    var  timer =  setInterval( "slideSwitch()",5000);
 $("#slideshow a img").hover(function(ev){
     a= 5000-timer;                      // finding the time lapsed
    clearInterval(timer);
}, function(ev){
    timer =  setInterval( "slideSwitch()",a);   // resume from the time paused
});
```

Hope this helps,Thank you

Comment: Worked like a charm! Awsome! Thank you very much!

Comment: One thing, after a few moments with the page opened, the slider star to act weird, images flickering, changing too fast, becoming a completely mass. Any reason for that? o.O